# How to reference an XML attribute using XPath?

Tags: xpath

My XML:

```
<root>
  <cars>
    <makes>
      <honda year="1995">
        <model />
        <!-- ... -->
      </honda>
      <honda year="2000">
        <!-- ... -->
      </honda>
    </makes>
  </cars>
</root>
```

I need a XPath that will get me all models for `<honda>` with year 1995.

so:

```
/root/cars/makes/honda
```

But how to reference an attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `/root/cars/makes/honda/@year`

**UPDATE**: reading your question again:

```
   /root/cars/makes/honda[@year = '1995']
```

Bottom line is: use @ character to reference xml attributes.

Answer (score 9):

> "I need a XPath that will get me all models for `<honda>` with year 1995."

That would be:

```
/root/cars/makes/honda[@year = '1995']/model
```